# Can't seem to use githubusercontent from a script

Tags: perl, github, lwp-useragent

I have been trying to download automatically some GitHub content from this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use File::Slurp::Tiny qw(write_file);
use v5.16;
my $dir = shift || ".";
my $previo = shift || "IV-2015-16";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0");
for my $d ( qw( ejercicios objetivos practicas sesiones ) ) {
    my $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JJ/$previo/master/$d/README.md";
    my $response = $ua->get( $url );
    if ($response->is_success ) {
        my $file = $response->decoded_content;
        say "$url gave $file";
        write_file($file, "$dir/$d/README.md" ) || die "Can't write file";
    } else {
        die "Can't download this $url because ". $response->status_line;
    }
}
```

URLs are correct, however it fails with

```
'_msg' => 'Can\'t connect to raw.githubusercontent.com:443'
'_rc' => 500
```

That is, returning a 500 error.

```
Can't download this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JJ/IV-2015-16/master/ejercicios/README.md because 500 Can't connect to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 at /tmp/cosas.pl line 19.
at /tmp/cosas.pl line 19.
```

I have tried to set the user agent, and it still does not work. I wonder if it needs authentication, however using wget or just putting this on the URL bar downloads stuff correctly. Any idea? Maybe some API banning or throttling?

Comment: Obvious question, but do you run this from a machine with internet connection?

Comment: Wouldn't have a "500" error if I didn't... I guess I could get a 404 error from a local proxy, but that's not the case. It works without a glitch using wget, it's only the client the one that does not work.

Comment: are you behind a proxy/firewall? works fine from here.

Comment: It works perfectly if I use wget or the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a connectivity issue. Your browser probably uses a proxy. `wget` also because environment variables are correctly set: `http_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `ALL_PROXY`...

But LWP::UserAgent does not uses those environment variables unless explicitely told to. Add this line just after the user agent construction:

```
$ua->env_proxy;
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is old, but people are likely to have the same question about LWP.

First, LWP cannot handle HTTPS unless you install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https).

Second, you mentioned in the comment that you know you are connected because you get a 500 error. That's simply not true. LWP uses 500 when it can't connect. That could be because there's no such host, the host is not accepting connections, or you are not connected to the network. All of those are 500 errors. Here, for example, I turn off networking, try to connect, and get a 500:

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1
ping: sending packet: No route to host
$ perl -MLWP::UserAgent -le 'print LWP::UserAgent->new->get(shift)->status_line' http://www.example.com
500 Can't connect to www.example.com:80 (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

But, I can fetch your files just fine:

```
$ perl -MLWP::UserAgent -le 'print LWP::UserAgent->new->get(shift)->status_line' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JJ/IV-2015-16/master/ejercicios/README.md
200 OK
```

However, if you want to grab files, there's the [Contents API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents) which has a specific endpoint for fetching READMEs (although only top-level ones). And, you can get them raw or interpreted. Using the API, you can look at rate limit information in the response headers.